# How can I confirm if an async EF6 await db.SaveChangesAsync() worked as expected?

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api2

My code looks like this:

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Delete(int id)
    {
        var userId = Int32.Parse(User.Identity.GetUserId());   
        UserTest userTest = await db.UserTests.FindAsync(id);
        if (userTest == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        if (userTest.UserId != userId)
        {
            return Unauthorized();
        }
        db.UserTests.Remove(userTest);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Ok();
    }
```

I think everything up to the db.SaveChangesAsync is okay but how can I confirm if the db.SaveChangesAsync works before doing a return Ok() ? Ideally I think I should be checking for exceptions and things but I am not sure how I could fit that into this code block.

Comment: using of await definitely waits for the method  db.SaveChangesAsync() to complete it's execution and it returns a value which shows the affected rows in DB.

Comment: What are you actually asking if below answers are "incorrect" ?

Comment: Kevin - It was not me that marked down both answers. I assume it was one of the other first ten to look at this post. I will upvote both.

Comment: @Alan: First ask yourself the question: How would I confirm `db.SaveChanges()` works? Then you just do the same thing for `await db.SaveChangesAsync()`.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "works". If you mean to confirm no Exception was thrown perhaps you should wrap it up with a try/catch. If you wish to confirm a line was deleted await db.SaveChangesAsync() returns the number of lines changed. It is possible (at least theoretically) that two user will simultenously work to delete the same id in the database. What would you like to happen in such a case? In any case - why not just have your method return true/false? why use a Task<IHttpActionResult> when you can just use Task<bool>?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From msdn:

```
public virtual Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
```

> Return Value Type: System.Threading.Tasks.Task A task that
>   represents the asynchronous save operation. The task result contains
>   the number of objects written to the underlying database.

Check if the result is greater than 0:

```
if(await db.SaveChangesAsync() > 0)
{
     .....
}
```

[More info here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220070(v=vs.113).aspx)

Another option is to wrap this with `try ... catch` block:

```
try
{
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return Ok();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return NotFound(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: What does that ok do?

Comment: Have look at the docs https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.ok(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: If the result is 0, does that necessarily mean that it was unsuccessful? If you track an entity and the state of the entity did not change, it will probably return 0. Or for delete, if an entity was deleted by another user in the meantime. But it was still "successful". Also the 2 options check for something entirely different. I'd rather use the second option or at least combine them.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following below :)

```
try {
    int writtenEntriesCount = await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    if(writtenEntriesCount > 0){
      // is saved
    }else{
     // is not saved
    }
} catch(e) {
    // handle error here
}
```

Comment: Hey @PrimeByDesign, you can wrap code in try-catch to get error, will update above code to include how to capture error/exception

Comment: I've just seen this, Thanks Kevin!

Answer (score 0):

I normally use this if it helps:

```
try
        {
            _context.Events.Add(entity);

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
            return new CommandResult() { IsSuccess = true };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new CommandResult() { IsSuccess = false,IsError =True, Message=ex.Message };
        }



public class CommandResult
{
    public bool IsSuccess { get; internal set; }
    public bool IsError { get; internal set; }
    public string Message { get; internal set; }
}
```