# SaveChangesAsync returns exception instead of 0

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

About SaveChangesAsync method, Microsoft says
it's a task that represents the asynchronous save operation. The task result contains the number of state entries written to the underlying database.

According to that, some programmers use if condition to check the number of rows affected after SaveChangesAsync is run.

Here is an example: [How can I confirm if an async EF6 await db.SaveChangesAsync() worked as expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28427473/how-can-i-confirm-if-an-async-ef6-await-db-savechangesasync-worked-as-expected)

But, what happens if an error occurs when calling SaveChangesAsync? Well, contrary to what I expected, which would be "0 lines affected", **an exception is thrown**, in most cases, a [DbUpdateException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbupdateexception?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)

> "Exception thrown by DbContext when the saving of changes to the database fails."

So, why are there several recommendations for using `if (await context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0)` once the result from database will never be zero, but instead, an exception?

Comment: It could be 0 if nothing changes but could also throw an Exception. This could be due to concurrency, a mismatched schema, data that does not fit the constraints, a check constraint error, referential integrity violation, etc. That is just proper design and the Exception or inner exception is usually detailed enough to let you know why it failed.

Comment: Try catching the exception with try/catch block and read the innerexception. Unique/Primary key violation, Fk violation etc...

Comment: Specifically look at the inner exception for the real error

Answer (score 3):

> So, why are there several recommendations for using `if (await context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0)` once the result from database will never be zero, but instead, an exception?

First off, there are **no** such official recommendations. The people who provided them have no idea of the semantics of the `SaveChanges` operation. Which by current [official EF Core documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.savechanges?view=efcore-5.0) is:

> **Returns**
> `Int32`
> The number of state entries written to the database.
>
> **Exceptions**
> `DbUpdateException`
> An error is encountered while saving to the database.
>
> `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`
> A concurrency violation is encountered while saving to the database. A concurrency violation occurs when an unexpected number of rows are affected during save. This is usually because the data in the database has been modified since it was loaded into memory.

This is for `SaveChanges`, but the same is for `Async` version after `await`ing it.

So, as it can be seen from the docs, the operation can return 0 and still be successful. It's because the smart update (load/modify/save) might not generate database operation. But still it is saved - because you don't ask "please force write this to database", but "please make sure this data is saved to the database". It's true that if you perform perform forced update, then 0 is never returned. But that's not essential at all.

The more important is, the success of the operation is determined as usual  by the lack of exception. I don't know what is the intended usage of the return value - it might be just because it is something "we can return". Or carry over from EF6 which in turn is carry over from ADO.NET etc. Or just use it for some logging if real database CUD occurred. Who knows. But, for sure one should **not** use it for checking the success as in these (anti) "recommendations".